# language and toolkit for fast plotting of live data from serial port

Tags: python, c, plot, serial-port, gtk

i'm trying to plot live data from the serial port (sent from an arduino board) and i just can't find anything that works. i've been onto this for a couple of days, tried a lot and never succeeded.
i manages to read data from the port using cat, C and python with very strange results on all of them. yesterday cat printed the data nicely to the terminal, today it only shows one line or two each time i run it. in C the data comes very dirty. in python it seems ok. while not perfect, the reading part is not the problem.
i tried to plot the data from python with matplotlib, which worked with a ever increasing delay, that made the plot useless. i couldn't get C and gtk to work. i tried python + chaco but i don't get how chaco works. i found myself jumping between different languages and modules to get this to work, but as i got none of them to work i keep jumping without getting to any solutions.

now, my question is:
which language, modules, gui-toolkit etc. would you recommend to use for this?

i know this a general question, and it is preferred to ask for specific things, but i'm really lost on this.
thanks.

Update:
i choose python, pyserial and pyqtgraph. serial is working, but the graphing isn't.
Update:
GOT IT!
this example is working.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
import serial

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

p = pg.plot()
p.setWindowTitle('live plot from serial')
curve = p.plot()

data = [0]
raw=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
raw.open()
ptr = 0

def update():
    global curve, data, ptr
    line = raw.readline()
    data.append(int(line))
    xdata = np.array(data, dtype='float64')
    print xdata
    curve.setData(xdata)
    ptr += 1
    app.processEvents()

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: What protocol are you using for the serial byte stream, and are you parsing/decoding it correctly, (I'm guessing 'none')?

Comment: none/don't know
i use the Serial.print() built into the arduino and port.readline() of pyserial. this yields me a string (i.e. 123,2332,1234) which i split up and check if there really are 3 values and ignore the corrupted ones.

Comment: I understand the plotting part is your main concern, and I've tried to answer that part of your question. You should also investigate why you are receiving (and discarding) corrupt packets.

Comment: It is likely that you have a good question or three in here---understanding the troubles you are having---but recommendation questions are right out.

Comment: as the problem is solved and the question doesn't comply with the rules it can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) to plot live ECG data sampled @ 500 Hz (x 12 channels x 16 bits/sample). It was easy to implement, fast and smooth and worked well enough for me.

Check out the `Updating Plot` example for instance.

[image]

Comment: this seems nice, but i'm running in an 'invalid data type' error.
see original post for code.